# Manually triggered select event does not send event details

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I am attemping to trigger the on select event handler by triggering the select event however when the event is triggered through code, the event details ((e.params)) is left undefined unlike when the select event is actually triggered by a manual selection

Is there any way to get the event details when trigger('select2:select') is used?

```
function filterRelevantClientsForSPAWithPreviousValues(){
    let tempSelectedClients = $('select[name=client_id]').val();
    console.log("Past selected client = "+tempSelectedClients);
    $('select[name=client_id]').empty();
    for(var i = 0; i < {{count($spa_client_list)}}; i ++){
      if({!! $spa_client_list !!}[i]['id'] == tempSelectedClients){
          var newOption = new Option({!!$spa_client_list!!}[i]['name'], {!!$spa_client_list  !!}[i]['id'], true, true);
          $('select[name=client_id]').append(newOption).trigger('change').trigger('select2:select');
      }
      else{
          var newOption = new Option({!!$spa_client_list!!}[i]['name'], {!!$spa_client_list  !!}[i]['id'], false, false);
          $('select[name=client_id]').append(newOption).trigger('change');
      }
    }
}
```

Event Handler

```
   $('select[name=client_id]').on('select2:select', function (e) {
        console.log("on select client 2 event has been triggered");
        console.log(e.params);
    })
```

Desired outcome
[image]

Actual results

[image]

Comment: You are using select2, it says in the docs that if you want an Event object, you need to pass it to the trigger. [select2 events](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#triggering-events)